# One-to-many spatial join in R

Tags: r, spatial-join, sp

I want to perform a spatial join (one-to-many relation) between two Spatial Dataframe layers in R. More specifically, I have a set of lines (SpatialLinesDataframe) that need to be joined to the ID of a neighborhood (SpatialPolygonsDataframe) if they overlap with it.

I tried using the over function (as indicated below) and get the following error:

```
over.list <- over(lines, neighorhood, returnList = TRUE)
```

> Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) : 
>     rgeos_binpredfunc_prepared: maximum returned dense matrix size exceeded

I presume this is due to the size of the `sp` objects (475365 and 170045, respectively). What is the best approach to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with a subset of your data in order to test your presumption?

Comment: Hi!  I did and it worked. But I need an approach that can scale to large spatial data frames. I managed to resolve the issue using sf  (see below).                                                                                                But I am curious to see if there is a way to approach this issue using sp. 
#join streets and neighborhoods                                                                         inter_sf <- st_join(lines_sf, neigh_sf)
 
  #leave only streets that overlap with neighborhoods
  streets_sub_sf <- inter_sf[neigh_sf, ]

Comment: IMO, I'd switch to `sf` instead of using `sp` since sf is more up to date and mostly faster!